# Is there any region that considers to or already uses Demarchy?

Tags: democracy, political-theory, political-system, sortition

According to [this article](https://www.prediki.com/meta/en/The-Open-Democracy-Manifesto-(-Demarchy-)/), Demarchy is a form of statistical representative democracy which rely on collective intelligence:

> Improving on the age-old model of sortition democracy, by which the
>   citizens of Ancient Athens and Serenissima Venice flourished and
>   prospered, the internet now facilitates an improved form of
>   decentralised self-governance by adding collective intelligence to the
>   mix. Citizens are no more impotent subjects to those in power. They
>   make all decisions themselves, in a participative and deliberative
>   process performed by a large number of parallel representative
>   sociodemographic samples from their midst.

This is advertised as having numerous advantages, such as legitimacy, neutrality, rationality and inclusive.

**Question:** is there any region (at least several thousand persons) that considers or already uses Demarchy or something very similar?

Comment: So this is direct democracy? With online referendums on every issue?

If so, I doubt that any country would use this, as the decision-making would be too slow and prone to hacking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The older definition of Demarchy refers to [sortition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sortition), or:

> In governance, sortition (also known as allotment or demarchy) is the
>   selection of political officials as a random sample from a larger pool
>   of candidates. The logic behind the sortition process originates from
>   the idea that "power corrupts."(citation needed) For that reason, when
>   the time came to choose individuals to be assigned to empowering
>   positions, the ancient Athenians resorted to choosing by lot.

And indeed there were regions that used this system in antiquity. Today, as far as I know, the use is far more limited but [Wikipedia mentions the use of it by some Amish communities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sortition#Modern_examples).

The definition you seem to be asking for is actually the one advanced by [John Burnheim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Burnheim) which assumes a stateless society (but not necessarily within the philosophical range of [Anarchism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anarchism)) ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Burnheim)).

> In his book Is Democracy Possible? The alternative to electoral
>   politics (1985) Burnheim used the term "demarchy" (created by
>   Friedrich Hayek in his Law, Legislation and Liberty) to describe a
>   political system without the state or bureaucracies, and based instead
>   on randomly selected groups of decision makers.

As far as I know no large scale example of this exists today.

---

**NOTE:** As a curiosity (as *representation in culture*) the only interesting representation of an even more progressive form of demarchism I read about was the [demarchist societies](http://revelationspace.wikia.com/wiki/Demarchists) of the [Revelation Space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revelation_Space) book series by [Alastair Reynolds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alastair_Reynolds):

> The Demarchists (pejoratively referred to by outsiders as zombies)
>   were a faction of humanity who had a political system of democratic
>   anarchy, or "Demarchy". The Demarchy functioned by means of a neural
>   implant that constantly sought the user's opinion on aspects of
>   Demarchist life.

[image: Alastair Reynolds Revelation Space book cover]

Answer (score 1):

Your question is quite broad, and the manifesto that you link to a bit more specific, but if we consider specifically the **Sortition** component of it, we can have a look at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sortition) (linked below your article).

In particular, it points to the use of sortition in history: besides the already cited Athens and Venice, Florence had it for a while, as well as some parts of Switzerland ([ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sortition#cite_note-15)) and some Indian villages ([ref](http://theencyclopediaofhinduism.tumblr.com/post/104798277303/uttaramerur-a-village-near-kanchipuram-in-the)).

The main current use of sortition is for [common-law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_law) based juries. But also punctually for some decisions process (cities' development).

The same Wikipedia page actually lists some [recent/current examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sortition#Modern_examples). Without reporting the whole list, one can point two examples:

- [Amish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amish) use the sortition as a part of the selection of their leaders,
- [Consensus Conferences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consensus_conferences) in Denmark attempts to provide a consultative "body" for policy making.